# PHP - self destruct message telegram bot

Tags: php, php-telegram-bot

I am building a telegram bot to send ads to my channels and I want them to be deleted after a certain period of time

But I need to get message id to delete it, when I run code like this

```
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$command = $update->message->text;
function message($mchat_id, $mtext)
{
    global $token;
    $ret=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot' .$token.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$mchat_id.'&text='.$mtext.'&parse_mode=HTML'));
    return $ret;
}
function delete($dchat_id, $dmsgid)
{
    global $token;
    file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/deleteMessage?chat_id='.$dchat_id.'&message_id='.$dmsgid);
}
if($command == "/start")
{
    $ret = message("$chat_id" , "$text");
    $msgid = $ret->result->message_id;
    $chatid = $ret->result->chat->id;
    sleep(3600);
    delete($chaid , $msgid);
}
```

It sends the text again and again every ~2 minutes forever and deletes each sent message after an hour.

Comment: `delete($chaid , $msgid);` You spelled chat wrong.

Comment: i spelled it wrong here in my code its right , sorry.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the revision halfer I will take that in concern in my next questions

Answer (score 0):

You used existing function called [delete()](http://php.net/delete), just rename that.

Comment: that is not the problem the function works fine the problem is It sends the text again and again and then delete them all